# Importance of inverse document frequency in calculation of elastic search relevance score

Tags: elasticsearch

I read in the documentation about how the relevance score is calculated. But I am still not able to understand why they have taken the inverse document frequency into consideration. How does inverse document frequency affect the relevancy of a document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, if a term T is very common (e.g. like stopwords, "and", "the", etc) and can be found in a great deal of your documents, you're probably not interested in getting all documents back and you probably don't want that the term T affects the scoring too much.

That's the job of the IDF part in the TF/IDF formula, which means that rarer terms will provide a higher contribution to the score, hence why the term frequency TF of term T in a given document is multiplied by the IDF of that term for the whole document corpus. In clear, the more documents contain a given term, the less relevant/discriminant that term should be.

A term "elephant" appearing a few times in a document D, but not necessarily in all other documents, will contribute to give document D a higher score than for all other documents.

A term "and" appearing in almost every documents will not contribute much to the score because the IDF will be negligible.